# How to verify AWS Lambda SnapStart optimization works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Context: I have lambda function that is using service reaching to S3 bucket for a specific object. I want to run it with snapstart optimization.

This function is using *S3Client.listObjects* method.

I’ve configured snapstart and published new version of lambda function. In this example version = 6. My API gateway is connected to that version.

After deployment I’ve check my function version with: **get-function-configuration** to see if snapstart optimisation in on and it is:

```
"SnapStart": {
"ApplyOn": "PublishedVersions",
"OptimizationStatus": "On"
}
```

On the other hand time of the invocation and log shows that something is not ok. Initial hit lasts 8s and next ones ~0.5s.
**Is snapstart on but I’ve missed smith else? Why do I get these looong executions times instead of close to 1s.**

See the logs:

```
RESTORE_START Runtime Version: java:11.v15  Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:<my-region>::runtime:…
RESTORE_REPORT Restore Duration: 246.03 ms

START RequestId: bd3b2c38-b82e-45aa-a095-91b422623c88 Version: 6
2023-02-20 15:00:18:934 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host=<my-special-bucket>.s3.<my-region>.amazonaws.com, port=443, encodedPath=, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent], queryParameters=[])
2023-02-20 15:00:20:733 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received successful response: 200
2023-02-20 15:00:21:052 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host=<my-special-bucket>.s3.<my-region>.amazonaws.com, port=443, encodedPath=/ABC/blahblah/file.json, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent, x-amz-te], queryParameters=[])
2023-02-20 15:00:21:199 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received successful response: 200
END RequestId: bd3b2c38-b82e-45aa-a095-91b422623c88
REPORT RequestId: bd3b2c38-b82e-45aa-a095-91b422623c88  Duration: 7450.73 ms    Billed Duration: 7595 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 129 MB Restore Duration: 246.03 ms Billed Restore Duration: 144 ms 

START RequestId: d81b3f76-be10-40e2-aa6e-6d563c76bdd6 Version: 6
2023-02-20 15:00:23:353 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host=<my-special-bucket>.s3.<my-region>.amazonaws.com, port=443, encodedPath=, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent], queryParameters=[])
2023-02-20 15:00:23:616 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received successful response: 200
2023-02-20 15:00:23:652 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host=<my-special-bucket>.s3.<my-region>.amazonaws.com, port=443, encodedPath=encodedPath=/ABC/blahblah/file.json, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent, x-amz-te], queryParameters=[])
2023-02-20 15:00:23:819 +0000 [main] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received successful response: 200
END RequestId: d81b3f76-be10-40e2-aa6e-6d563c76bdd6
REPORT RequestId: d81b3f76-be10-40e2-aa6e-6d563c76bdd6  Duration: 506.11 ms Billed Duration: 507 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 132 MB
```

Comment: Where do you initialize your AWS service clients? My guess is that it's in the function handler. To make SnapStart useful, you need to perform initialization before the first invocation of the handler.

Comment: Your guess is incorrect. Whole initialization is in static section out of handler method though still in class.

Comment: :shrug: without showing your actual code and Lambda configuration, you're inviting people to guess. Maybe someone else will have a better guess.